# Copy an msi to memory, then create a Database object from it

Tags: c#, windows-installer, dtf

I'm very much in the deep end here, so please accept my apologies for not really knowing what I'm on about.

My aim is to take an existing msi, make some alterations to it, then create a transform from it, leaving the msi in it's original state. I'm using DTF (part of WiX), as suggested in many other questions.

My problem stems from the fact that I need two database objects to create the transform; the altered database and the reference. Obviously I can't create two object from the same file because the first object locks it. The trivial option is to create a copy of the file in a temp directory and create a new object from the new filepath. However, I really want to avoid writing to disk except to save the transform, as the program may be used with varying mixtures of VMs, local storage and network storage.

From what I gather, DTF does allow you to create a database object from a handle, so my current approach is to somehow create a copy of the msi in memory with a handle and then pass that to the database constructor to create a temporary object that I can make changes to before creating a transform off it.

I'm at a loss of how to achieve this, though, and I'm not even sure it's possible. A MemoryMappedFile seemed like a good place to start, but when creating one from a file it's persistent and I can't work out how to either make a non-persistent mmf based on a file or create a non-persistent mmf and then read the msi into it.

Is there any feasible way to create a transform with only one msi on the disk? Open to absolutely any ideas/guidance/appeals to just accept writing to the disk because I'm clearly out of my depth.

Comment: Using Process Explorer to look at what Orca does when you author a transform, it seems to create a temp copy of the MSI. If MS do this in a tool designed for editing MSIs and authoring transforms, I'd guess that there's not a better way (but could be wrong, so putting this as a comment rather than an answer)

Comment: Good luck, I've gone as far as I've gone.  Hopefully something I commented will lead you to a solution rather then distract you from it.  One simple solution would be to install a RAM drive product.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are may be stuck here. The underlying Windows Installer database APIs will lock the .msi file if you open it for modification. That will prevent any other handles from being opened to the .msi file.

However, there is one thing to try. I'm not sure this is possible with DTF (I know how to attempt it in native code) but:

1. Open the .msi file for edit (you'll want to experiment with both direct and transacted modes since one may work where the other does not).
2. Create a string (yes, a string) that is `"#" + the numeric value of the datbase handle`.  In native code you can do essentially a `printf("#%u", hDatabase);`. A `String.Format` using the DTF `IntPtr handle` of the `Database` object might get you the same.
3. Pass the `#HANDLENUMBER` string to the open database API as read-only this time.
4. Modify the the database with the first handle.
5. Try generating the transform.

If that doesn't work, there are a number of other things you might try.  First, open the original handle as read-only then open the database in step 4 as transact or direct (basicaly switch them). If that doesn't work, try committing the database before step 5.  However, committing the database will probably require writing to disk (thus the temp file).

Anyway, if the above does not work, I'm quite convinced it is not possible to accomplish what you want with the available APIs. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but neither of them work. If the database is open in read-only, you can only open it in read-only. If it's open in direct or transact, you can't open it at all. Another poster had a good idea, but it's something to investigate when the boss isn't on my back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shucks. Didn't have much hope it would work. You'll need to put a copy of the file on disk.

Comment: Rob, your way better at unmanaged code then I am... google "ntfs alternate streams"  and see if that could make sense from an MsiOpenDatabase() perspective. I also see a new namespace in .NET 4.0 called System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.

Comment: "NTFS alternate streams" are just more bits on disk addressed a little differently. Memory mapped files could work *except* that the Windows Installer APIs require paths on disk not file handles. That paths on disk is what kills this. That and the fact that it's OLE Structured Storage files under everything. Those are a bit painful in their own right.

Comment: Good to know. I sometimes reach deep in situations like this just to see what might stick to the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it. I copy the base MSI to a temp file, modify it and then generate the transform using the two files.  Not sure why this would all need to be done in memory.

```
private void GenerateTransform(string baseMSI, string outputMST)
{
    string tempMSI = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".msi");
    File.Copy(baseMSI, tempMSI, true);

    using (var baseDatabase = new Database(baseMSI, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
    {
        using (var tempDatabase = new Database(tempMSI, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
        {
            // Do Stuff Here

            // Finally, Generate Transform
            tempDatabase.GenerateTransform(baseDatabase, outputMST);
            tempDatabase.CreateTransformSummaryInfo(baseDatabase, outputMST, TransformErrors.None, TransformValidations.None);
        }
    }

    File.Delete(tempMSI);
}
```

Comment: The whole point of the OPs question seemed to be that they wanted to avoid making a copy on disk, if at all possible.

Comment: Sure, but why?  Is there really a reason or is this just all new to him and he assumed that's what he would need? ("Open to absolutely any ideas/guidance/appeals to just accept writing to the disk because I'm clearly out of my depth")

Comment: "The trivial option is to create a copy of the file in a temp directory and create a new object from the new filepath. However, I really want to avoid writing to disk"

Comment: The use a RAM disk. Seriously, I can't imagine anyone generating so many transforms that they have real world concerns about the I/O cost.  Can you?

Comment: It's more about the questionable nature of our environment that I have no control over. Doing everything in memory just saves on disk writes, and when we occasionally get vendor msis in excess of a GB, that could save some time.

Comment: I should add, writing to disk takes a long time for us, but RAM is not an issue (4GB dedicated, burst to 8GB, per machine).

And besides that, copying a file is simple. I'm not going to learn anything new doing that. If I'm stuck in the deep end I might as well start trying to swim.

Thanks for the input, though. :)

Comment: I would go post a stack overflow question that asks if there is anyway to load a file into a memory stream and then trick windows into using that file whenever a process tries to reference a file path.  I wouldn't mention MSI.

Comment: I did some googling and there seems to be a concept called NTFS (Alternate) Streams.  It seems to be a way to create a virtual path in NTFS for an in memory stream.  I don't know if the MsiOpenDatabase API function would accept it as an argument but it might.

Comment: As a vendor, I would *NEVER* create an MSI that's 1+GB.  100MB is about the largest I ever do before splitting the MSI and CAB.  Windows has to have contigious memory to process an MSI and it does all kinds of security checks on startups.  Very large MSI's create problems in these areas.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but maybe you can create your copy of the MSI using:

```
Handle copyOfMSI = CreateFile(..., dwShareMode=FILE_SHARE_WRITE, ..., dwFlagsAndAttributes=FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE)`
```

Write your MSI to it, don't close copyOfMSI, work from that file, and finally close copyOfMSI.

Comment: FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY actually looks like a really elegant way of doing it and is a good safeguard should the 8GB of memory be used up. I feel like this warrants more investigation than I have time for. I'

Comment: You'll still end up with a file on disk, it'll just go away when the handle is released.